# How can I change the type of a button from "button" to "submit" with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following form:

```
<form id="xx">
<button type="button">Submit</button>
<button type="button">Submit and Close</button>
<button type="button">Close</button>
</form>
```

How can I change the type of my buttons that contain the word "Submit" from a type "button" to a type "submit"?

Comment: Worth mentioning that none of the solutions here will work in Internet Explorer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('button').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf('submit') != -1;
}).prop('type','submit');
```

first filter for buttons which have "submit" as text, then change the property.

Answer (score 3):

I your button had an id e.g. "button" this could be acieved in the following way:

```
$('#button').prop('type', 'submit');
```

If you wish to change the attribute of all the buttons with the text "Submit", this could be achieved in the following way:

```
$('button').each(function(){
    if($(this).text().indexOf("Submit") != -1){
        $(this).prop('type','submit');
    }
});
```

Comment: My buttons don't have an id of '#button' and I can't control the ids as this is not an area of code I can modify. I need to modify given exactly the above. thanks

Comment: `If you wish to change the attribute of all the buttons...` But the question was specifically to only change the buttons which contain the word "Submit"

Comment: Edited to reflect your requirements

Comment: @Marisu - Please see Andy's answer for a solution to the question. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't work for me (jQ 1.8) - 'Error: type property can't be changed'

Comment: @deifwud yeah `type` is a property and has to be changed with `prop` instead of `attr` (in 1.8 at least)

Comment: Changed this to prop, note i have not actually been able to test my answer, sorry for any inconvinience this may have caused.

Answer (score 1):

create the id in the button and do the following thing

```
$('#buttonid').replaceWith($('#buttonid').clone().attr('type', 'submit'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (untested):

```
$('button').each(function() {
    if($(this).text().match(/submit/i)) {
        $(this).prop('type', 'submit');
    }
});
```

**edit**

It's worth pointing out that this, and all of the other answers here will **not** work in Internet Explorer:

> Note: jQuery prohibits changing the type attribute on an  or
>    element and will throw an error in all browsers. This is
>   because the type attribute cannot be changed in Internet Explorer.

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

(I've tested this with `.prop()` as well, and although no error is thrown, it doesn't work)